# My iphone application crashes when i use table view

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *theCell=[UITableViewCell alloc];
     theCell=[theCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

      NSLog(@"%i",[table count]);

         theCell.textLabel.text=[table objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  

    return theCell;
}
```

There are three values inserted in a file Values.plist and they populate the NSArray "table" in the function viewDidLoad() but my application crashes at

```
" theCell.textLabel.text=[table objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  "
But the line "NSLog(@"%i",[table count]);" works and shows me 3
please help .
```

Comment: It'd help to post the error message that you get when the app crashes. Take a look in the console to find it. The stack trace can be helpful, too.

Comment: so whats the error message ?? make sure that you have string values in your array.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard implementation:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }


       cell.textLabel.text = [table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

As a side note this is the ARC implementation. If your not using ARC just add an  autoRelease:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autoRelease];
```

also make sure your dataSource numberOfSections is set right:

```
return 1;
```

and numberOfRows is set to the array:

```
return [table count];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of following issues:

1) Make sure that NSArray has values i.e it is populated.

2) Also try `NSLog(@"%d",[table count]);`

I think you should better go with `%d` and not `%i`.

Hope this helps you.